# Consume WCF with BasicHttpBinding and Windows Authentication

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF Service, using the basichttpbinding and windows authentication (no anonymous),

The WCF service is hosted in the domain server
I need to consume the service from a server which is out of the domain, that server doesn't join domain, that is a workgroup. Is that possible? please help for a code snippet.

The configuration like below

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="defaultBinding" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior" name="namespace.MyService">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBinding" contract="namespace.IMyService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="abc.xyz.com"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Edited: here is my client code

```
_securityServiceClient = new SecurityServiceClient(); 
_securityServiceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "lto3";
_securityServiceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Lydowe@1982";
```

I got this error

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from
>   the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Comment: This is one of the most basic scenarios, covered in all WCF tutorials. What have you tried and what was the problem? Where is the client code?

Comment: hi, thank you for your looking, I got this message {"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."} and here is my client code _securityServiceClient = new SecurityServiceClient(); 
                    _securityServiceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "domain\\account";
                    _securityServiceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

Comment: hello, can you please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
_securityServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
            new NetworkCredential("lto3", "Ludowe@1982");
```

As per the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.windows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ClientCredentials.Windows is how you specify the credentials to use when using windows authentication.

Comment: thanks, but this property is readonly ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential

Comment: oh, I got the "read only" exception just 2 times ane now it gone :(

Comment: You get the read only exception if you've already used the client once already. As soon as a call is made, the credentials object is made read only.